# Performance Testing - Does the tester set up the server environment?

Tags: performance

I am new to Performance testing!
When performance testing web applications, are the web server, load balancer and web application server installed and configured by the same person doing the actual performance testing itself?

Comment: Well if you know how to do that, sure you can. Usually the test environment is provided to the tester depending on the requirement of the project.

Comment: In an ideal scenario, it is not job of performance tester to install and configure Application server. But if you know it then no issues in doing it. Actually it is beneficial if you have the knowledge. That way you ll be able to ensure if everything is set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the size and nature of the organization.

- In a small 10 person startup you get to do a lot of setup and installing
- In a medium size company you may or may not have a devops department that can do it for you.
- In a large company with a large IT group it is more likely that another group or individual will be doing this task for you.
- In well regimented, e.g. army or highly regulated and security conscious, e.g. banking, environments it is more likely that you will use a predefined setup created for you by others.
- In some organizations using a SAAS model and remote resources this is all done through some predefined tools, scripts, templates and configurations.

In many organizations it will also depend on your abilities.  If you already have the abilities you may get to do it.

Comment: That answer is equally good if you replace "performance testing" and "regression testing".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of a performance tester from [http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/performance-testing)

> Performance testing is the process of determining the speed or effectiveness of a computer, network, software program or device. This process can involve quantitative tests done in a lab, such as measuring the response time or the number of MIPS (millions of instructions per second) at which a system functions. Qualitative attributes such as reliability, scalability and interoperability may also be evaluated. Performance testing is often done in conjunction with stress testing.

So as far as your question is concerned, web application testing will be done by accessing the backgroup API's of your site. I would recommend looking into some beginning guides of a performance testing tool called [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). As a general rule, a performance tester will not be in charge of setting up the environment to test.